# Removing the Onedrive Documents folder?

Tags: windows-10, onedrive, documents

I don't like that onedrive is using my actual Documents folder as default. I don't like seeing the path with onedrive in it. Like if I'm saving a project, it saves inside the onedrive path.

I tried unlinking my pc with it, then uninstalling the program, then nearly deleted my whole actual "documents" folder inside the Onedrive path which I then figured out it was still connected to my real documents. (I recovered a few things from it so everything's cool)

I just recently recovered from some Windows update trouble, I wasn't able to boot into windows and I just recovered all my projects and personal files. I was able to get rid of Onedrive and not have any trouble with it being linked with my actual documents folder. This was about more than a year ago.

I've installed Onedrive again to see if I can permanently unlink my folder.

I have Windows 10, Any help?

Answer (score 1):

What MS never explicitly tells you is that turning on "**Backup**" for a folder 
[image]
re-directs the folder location from its default:

`%USERPROFILE%\<FolderName>`

to

`%USERPROFILE%\OneDrive\<FolderName>`

and moves any files found in the default **Documents** to the OneDrive **Documents**.

Turning off "**Backup**" will restore the default location, but (IIRC), you have to move the files manually.

With "**Backup**" turned off, only those files you explicitly save or move the the OneDrive folders will be synced with the cloud storage.

Comment: I don't have backup set up on my pc. Nevertheless, I can't delete Documents link as well - it keeps respawning and syncing each time I set up OneDrive on the PC :(

Comment: Unless you explicitly prevent it, **OneDrive* "backup" is set up for you when you create a login on the PC. What "link" are you trying to delete? Have you tried relocating **Documents** under **This PC** via  the `Location` tab in its **Properties** dialog?

Comment: I finally managed to delete this link. Now it’s not present inside OneDrive anymore. Not sure “what it was” before :)

Answer (score 0):

This process will allow you to move your OneDrive folder to the location of your choice:

1. Unlink your OneDrive account (Right Click on OneDrive Icon | Settings | Account Tab | Unlink this PC)
2. Open File Explorer and enter **%USERPROFILE%** (if it is not there navigate to where it is located)
3. Select your OneDrive folder and Click on the Home tab (top left corner) | Select the Move To Button | Select where you want the folder to be located
4. Relaunch OneDrive and Enter your Email | Click Sign In
5. When you get to the following screen click on the Change Location link (see picture) | Navigate to the location from step 3 and click select folder
   [image: OneDrive Folder Choice]

   - Note: if you get a Warning of "A OneDrive folder already on this PC" click "Use this Folder Button
     [image: Warning Window]
6. Click Next to finish the process