# Sync only some folders from My Documents to OneDrive

Tags: windows-10, onedrive

I have the default OneDrive with 5GB, and I sync My Documents folder to it.

The issue occurs when I get too much data in My Documents and I want to deselect some folders from syncing. But as I see, these deselected folders simply disappear from My Documents and are nowhere to be found in my computer. I also noticed that OneDrive actually cancelled the default My Documents path and created one of its own which is incredibly frustrating.

Is there a way to sync all my Documents folder to OneDrive but some specific folders that I select?

Comment: 1 Could you be more specific about what you want to do? Does one of these answer your question?  https://superuser.com/questions/1329689/how-to-exclude-a-specific-file-or-directory-from-onedrive-within-the-onedrive-fo  https://superuser.com/questions/1542310/removing-the-onedrive-documents-folder/1543022#1543022